# Which works of Hegel and Bismarck is Paul Ryan referring to?

Tags: united-states, political-theory

In [this video](https://youtu.be/3nVoF2NunUQ?t=410), Paul Ryan says that early progressives believe that "...we're all rubes and doobs(?) and we don't know enough so we have to delegate our power to these smart people..."

Can anyone provide references for this claim?

I'm happy to migrate this to the Philosophy SE in the event that this question is not political in nature. I figured it would get rejected by Philosophy SE since it has a political context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Which works of Hegel and Bismarck is Paul Ryan referring to?*

Not sure about "works of" Bismark, but Hegel seems clear enough.

[Hegel’s Social and Political Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-social-political/)

> Hegel’s main work was the *Elements of the Philosophy of Right* (“*PR*”) first published in 1821.

[10. The State](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-social-political/#Stat)

> The real power is behind the throne and held by an educated governing cabinet [*Ministerium*], often referred to as the bureaucracy. It is these advisors to the monarch who propose new laws, via the responsible cabinet minister. These ministers, and not the monarch, are answerable to the legislature whose role is to consider proposals and either enact or reject them.

Ryan was likely referring to [Otto von Bismarck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_von_Bismarck) "a conservative German statesman, diplomat, and writer."

In particular, Bismarck through [social legislation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_von_Bismarck#Social_legislation), "pursued a conservative state-building strategy designed to make ordinary Germans — not just his own Junker elite — more loyal to throne and empire, implementing the modern welfare state in Germany in the 1880s."

Among the legislation was: Sickness Insurance Law of 1883, Accident Insurance Law of 1884, and Old Age and Disability Insurance Law of 1889. As well as closer ties between workers (through unions) and the state.